# How to round all corners on a PCB in Altiium

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium, cad

All my PCB's have round corners, so you can't hurt yourself, and so it is easier to fit it into a rack.
Now with altium i always have drag the edges in the Board Shape Editor to make them round. I have to repeat this for each corner, and the "roundness" is always different for each corner. Is there a way to round every corner to the same amount/radius?

I've been working with altium for years now and i still haven't figured out this one thing. It always bugs me.

Comment: Does it really need to be the same radius or are you being a little OCD?

Comment: @Andyaka you're right, it would work just fine with them being a little bit different. But i'm working in semi-industrial designs, so one would expect all corners to be the same.

Comment: Why not just draw the outline using appropriate snap settings on the arc ends and then 'define from selected objects'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Altium, you can define the board outline by first drawing an outline (usually in a mechanical layer), selecting this outline and then go to Design->Board Shape->Define from selected objects. 
This way you can use standard line/arc tools to make your rounded edges. If you want perfect consistency, you can just draw one arc and copy-paste it to all other corners. 
[image]

Comment: Personally, I think you should always define the shape in the keep-out layer and use this method. 1: many times I've ordered boards and forgot to put the board shape into the keepout later. 2: its way easier to define shapes than the board editor.